# HTML Positioning: Postion two objects relative to a third object without disrupting the flow

Tags: html, css, position

Okay, so this is going to be hard to explain, so please ask questions if I am not clear

In my html page, I have a main "container" div that has multiple divs within it, but each of the divs inside the container are placed into one of two columns (so if there is a div in the container, it is either in the left column or the right column)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="column1">
    <div id="item1-1"></div>
    <div id="item1-2"></div>
    <div id="item1-3"></div>
  </div column1>
  <div id="column2">
    <div id="item2-1"></div>
    <div id="item2-2"></div>
    <div id="item2-3"></div>
  </div column2>
</div container>
```

[NOTE: I know the syntax is incorrect, I am just making it easier to read]

So, in other words, I want two columns of divs that can vary in size (so the page size can vary), and so that item1-2 appears below item1-1, etc. The problem here is I want the divs in the container to appear inside of it, so I cannot use absolute or relative positioning.  Something is telling me I should be using a table, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

So, my question is: using only html and css, is there any to do exactly what is above?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see the problem with your HTML should the proper CSS be applied to it. BTW, HTML like `</div container>` is invalid.

Comment: Your HTML syntax is not correct. What is `</div column2>` supposed to mean? Correct me if I'm wrong - you want two columns, one on the left, and one on the right with other divs inside appearing one under another?

Comment: Yes I know the syntax is incorrect, I wrote the </div> tags in there so it is easier to read. @DiH Yes that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: make `</div column1>` and `</div column2>` just say `</div>`

Second: CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#column1, #column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: In addition, you may want to apply `overflow: hidden` to `#container`. This will force the container to take the height of its floated children into account in its own height.

Comment: Thanks so much, this actually worked!  Now, if I want to add say 15px of padding, would I need to change the width, and by how much?

Comment: I would add padding or margin to something inside the columns, because its never going to work out perfectly adding up the percent with a px padding value. Or you can add like `padding: 2%;` and then `width: 46%;`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the look you want you should use [CSS `float` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp). However, to avoid problems with parent container not displaying correctly, consider following one of the two possible [solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/5J8f5/1/):

Adding a div after floating elements with

```
clear: both
```

or applying code below to your parent div

```
overflow: hidden
```